# In Locke and Key, how does this person survive?

Tags: comics, locke-and-key

In Locke and Key,

> Bode's soul is separated from his body

and at the end

> his body is destroyed, but then his brother uses what looks like the animal key to rescue him.

How does this work? From earlier in the comic, I thought that

> the animal key changes your body from one animal into another, while Bode doesn't have a body. Or is the implication that the bird volunteered to give its body to Bode to inhabit for...reasons (it wouldn't have been able to join its buddies) and once Bode did that, the bird body was put through the animal door...?

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't realize there was already a tag for the series. Didn't even bother looking, it seemed so unlikely. Thanks for the edit @Jonah

Comment: Any help here? "*There’s always been an out for the death of Bode Locke, because while his body may be dead, his spirit has been kept safe behind the Ghost Door. That still doesn’t lessen the impact of seeing his funeral and the way his family reacts to the reality of his death."* - http://www.avclub.com/article/joe-hill-and-gabriel-rodriguez-end-locke-amp-key-w-200692

Comment: That looks to be exactly it. The same thing is said on the Wikia (http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Bode_Locke) and a Reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/1t61df/so_locke_and_key_finishedspoilers/).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I know nothing about this comic. If you want to turn that into an answer, you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a Word of God answer from the author, but several other people have suggested the same sequence of events:

- [AVClub](http://www.avclub.com/article/joe-hill-and-gabriel-rodriguez-end-locke-amp-key-w-200692)
- [Locke and Key Wikia entry on Bode](http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Bode_Locke#Omega)
- [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/1t61df/so_locke_and_key_finishedspoilers/)

In *[Keys to the Kingdom](http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Bode_Locke#Keys_to_the_Kingdom)*:

> Zack took Bode back to Keyhouse, calling out for Sam Lesser. Zack explained that he would inhabit Bode's body, while Sam could take Zack's. Zack threw Bode through the Ghost Door, before taking Bode's body himself. Sam inhabited Zack's body, but was then killed by Kinsey. Bode, trapped without a body, was unable to communicate with anyone, or warn his family that Dodge was impersonating him.

In *[Omega](http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Bode_Locke#Omega)*:

> Tyler went to the Keyhouse after Bode's funeral and followed a sparrow to the Ghost Door through which it flew. Ghost Bode entered the dead sparrow and Tyler used the Animal Key on the well house which fully returned Bode to life.

So, the basic sequence of events (sorry... spoiler blocks don't support lists apparently):

> Zack took over Bode's body by virtue of separating his spirit at the Ghost Door. Bode communicated with some sparrows, one of which flew to the Ghost Door and had its spirit split away from its body. Bode inhabited the sparrow's body. Tyler used the Animal Key to change the sparrow's body to that of Bode. The sparrow may forever wander the property as a ghost.

### Reference

- [Ghost Door](http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_Key)
- [Animal Key](http://lockekey.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Key)

Comment: I will try to edit in pictures tonight.

Comment: Okay so it's as I suspected then. Gotcha. Thank you very much, I was wondering if I was crazy. Poor sparrow spirit :(

Comment: The way the panels are laid out, I don't see how I could properly reproduce the images without just posting them wholesale, so I will keep to my textual description and the links. :)